# Запрос с выборкой диапазона элементов из БД

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Переменная содержит цифры (id), перечисленные через запятую. Необходимо составить запрос с выборкой диапазона, который попадает в эту переменную. Значение строковое, по идее должен устраивать php в исходном виде. Сам запрос:

```
$cats_id = '5,6,7,8'

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM goods WHERE item_cat_id IN(:cats_id) ORDER BY item_title';
        $data = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $data->bindValue (':cats_id', $cats_id);
        $data->execute();
        $goods = $data->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Но запрос не проходит...

Comment: вы добавляете строку, то получается что вы ищите `cat_id IN ('qwerty')`, *qwerty* написал, чтобы поняли как это видит mysql. Т.е. надо либо через `IN (?, ?, ?...)` делать, либо приводить `$cats_id` к нужному виду, чтобы в итоге было `IN('1', '2', '3')`

Comment: ВОРОН, как-то так [ссылка](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition) ?

Comment: так вы посмотрите что там делается, явно не то же что у вас, а примерно то, что писал я

Comment: Я так понял, что там примерно то же самое и делается - происходит вывод позиций с определёнными значениями ячейки. Писал выборку по примеру, но там происходит соединение с базой через MySQLi и переменную вставляют прямо в строку запросу. Неужели такая разница в синтаксисе, то, что в одном варианте делается в один шаг то в другом нужно ещё через три функции пропустить...(

Comment: @Torawhite Так если вы этот список просто вставите в строку запроса сразу, а не через bindvalue то у вас как раз все заработает. `"SELECT * FROM goods WHERE item_cat_id IN($cats_id) ORDER BY item_title";`

Comment: @Mike нашёл решение [здесь](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/907806/php-mysql-using-an-array-in-where-clause)

Answer (score 1):

При работе с подготовленными выражениями ПДО важно понимать, что [плейсхолдер может представлять только строку или число](http://phpfaq.ru/pdo#in). Ни ключевое слово, ни идентификатор, ни часть строки или набор строк через стандартный плейсхолдер подставить нельзя. Поэтому для данного случая строку с плейсхолдерами приходится формировать руками:

```
$cats_id = [5,6,7,8];
$in  = str_repeat('?,', count($cats_id) - 1) . '?';
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM goods WHERE item_cat_id IN($in) ORDER BY item_title';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($cats_id);
$goods = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Что возвращает нас в каменный век ручного формирования запросов, но увы, ПДО не предоставляет готового функционала для подобных задач.

В идеальном же мире код выглядел бы как

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM goods WHERE item_cat_id IN(?a) ORDER BY item_title';
$goods = $db->getAll($sql, $cats_id);
```